# Воспроизведение выбранной музыки в определенное время

Tags: c#, winforms, mp3

При нажатии кнопки "Выбрать" должен открываться Проводник и пользователь выбирает mp3 файл
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в определенное время должен воспроизвестись этот файл
Его можно воспроизвести вот так

```
 private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          var fileContent = string.Empty;
          var filePath = string.Empty;
          using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
          {
              openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
              openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
              openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
              openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

              if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
              {
                  //Get the path of specified file
                  filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

                  //Read the contents of the file into a stream
                  var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();

                  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                  {
                      fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                  }
              }
          }
    }
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (label1.Text == label2.Text + ":00" && metroRadioButton1.Checked == true)
        {

            this.Text = WMP.versionInfo;
            WMP.URL = openFileDialog.FileName;
            WMP.controls.play();

            button2.Enabled = true;

        }
```

Где label1 это точное время, а label2 время когда нужно воспроизвести файл
Главный вопрос как реализовать выбор файла пользователем и его воспроизведение?

Comment: [OpenFileDialog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а как написать переменную тут WMP.URL = @"D:\muzika.mp3";

Comment: Вам же скинули документацию... `WMP.URL = openFileDialog.FileName`

Comment: обновите ваш код, как вы написали

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц обновил

Comment: первую ссылку изучите пожалуйста

Comment: Все заработало надо было openfiledialog при загрузке формы объявлять, Всем спасибо